# Why is *ptr.member wrong and (*ptr).member right?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I know that if I have a pointer in C programming language, and I have to point to a struct, I do:

```
struct mystruct S;
struct mystruct *ptr;
ptr=&S;
ptr->member=5;
```

I understood this, but I do not understand the reason why, if I do:

```
ptr=&S;
(*ptr).member=5;
```

`*ptr` should point to the first address of the struct, but why doesn't it work if I do this:

```
*ptr.member=5;
```

Comment: Because of the [Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a struct and a pointer to the struct:

```
  struct mystruct S;
  struct mystruct *ptr;
```

Now you store in **ptr** the **address** of that struct

```
  ptr = &S;
```

When you need to access one member of that struct through a pointer, you have TWO alternative syntaxes

```
  (*ptr).member = 5;
```

and

```
  ptr->member = 5;
```

The two syntaxes are **equivalent** and do **exactly the same action**.

Is only a matter of personal taste.

In your question you have an error, because you wrote:

```
(*p).member = 5;
```

Instead of

```
(*ptr).member = 5;
```

Hence the error

One last tip:

```
(*ptr).member = 5;
```

and

```
*ptr.member = 5;
```

Are different things

(*ptr).member = 5; means that you get the address pointed by **ptr** and then store 5 in the field named *member*

*ptr.member = 5; means that you get the address pointed by **ptr.member** and then store 5 in the memory pointed by that address.

Answer (score 2):

Operators have [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence): the member access operator `.` has the highest precedence, while dereference `*` has the next highest precedence. So `*p.member` attempts to find the member `member` of a pointer to `mystruct` and then dereference it. Since a `*mystruct` does not have a member called `member`, this is an error.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a structure

```
struct A
{
    int x;
};
```

and an object of the structure type

```
A a;
```

then to access its data member `x` you have to write

```
a.x = 5;
```

Or you can write

```
( &a )->x = 5;
```

Now if you have a pointer of type `struct A *` that initialized by the address of the object `a`

```
struct A *pa = &a;
```

then expression `*pa` gives the object `a` itself. So you may write

```
( *pa ).x = 5;
```

So now compare. On the one hand

```
a.x = 5;       and      ( *pa ).x = 5;
```

and on the other hand

```
( &a )->x = 5; and      pa->x = 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the access to member operator (the dot) has precedence over the dereferenciation (`*`).

So, your expression is equivalent to:

```
*(p.member) = 5
```

And `p.member` is not a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Unary `*` has a lower precedence than the `.` and `->` member selection operators, so `*p.member` is parsed as `*(p.member)`; in other words, you're attempting to dereference the result of `p.member`.  This has two problems:

- `p` is a pointer type, so the compiler will complain that you're trying to use the `.` operator on something that isn't a struct or union type;
- `member` *isn't* a pointer type, so you can't apply the unary `*` to it.

`(*p).member` is equivalent to `p->member`; both dereference `p` before accessing `member`.